# Which are the recommended books for an introductory study of complex manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, textbook-recommendation

Are there any good introductory type of books that is focus on complex manifolds?
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest Hirzebruch's "Topological methods in algebraic geometry".

Comment: Matsushima's"Differentiable Manifolds" if you jus want the basics. For deformation of complex manifolds I like "Advances in Moduli theory" by Shimizu. But if you want all modern techniques you will need Griffith and Harris'"Principles of Algebraic Geometry" or http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Huybrechts [Complex Geometry](http://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/2012/Geometry/Huybrechts.pdf)
 is excellent, and has some more recent stuff.

Griffiths and Harris [Principles of Algebraic Geometry](http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=575500) is a great classic.

Barths, Peters and Van Den Ven [Compact Complex Surfaces](http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=596261) gives a nice explanation of the classification of surfaces, which gives lots of nice examples, including nonalgebraic ones.

Beauville, [Complex Algebraic Surfaces](http://lib.freescienceengineering.org/view.php?id=3865) covers the classification of surfaces in the algebraic category.

Demailly, [Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) is more comprehensive, from the transcendental point of view.

Answer (score 3):

MR2359489 Wells, Raymond O., Jr. Differential analysis on complex manifolds. With a new appendix by Oscar Garcia-Prada. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 65. Springer, New York, 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "[Complex Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/082184055X)" by James Morrow and Kunihiko Kodaira. Kodaria is a very good lecturer who explains things really well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having two or three books around. Sometimes you understand one book's explanation of a topic better than the others. I also found it helpful to read a book on Riemann surfaces, such as Gunning or Springer at the same time.